# Converting the Fourier series solution of a Dirichlet problem (heat equation) in to an integral equation with a suitable kernal

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I have met with a multiple select question:

Q. Let $u(x, t)$ be a solution of the heat equation $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2},$$ in a rectangle $[0, \pi] \times[0, T]$ subject to the boundary conditions $$u(0, t)=u(\pi, t)=0,0 \leq t \leq T,$$ and the initial condition $$u(x, 0)=\varphi(x), 0 \leq x \leq \pi.$$ If $f(x)=u(x, T)$, then which of the following is/are true for a suitable kernel $k(x, y)$ ?

(1) $\int_0^\pi k(x, y) \varphi(y) d y=f(x), \quad 0 \leq x \leq \pi$,

(2) $\varphi(x)+\int_0^\pi k(x, y) \varphi(y) d y=f(x), 0 \leq x \leq \pi$,

(3) $\int_0^x k(x, y) \varphi(y) d y=f(x), 0 \leq x \leq \pi$,

(4) $\varphi(x)+\int_0^x k(x, y) \varphi(y) d y=f(x), 0 \leq x \leq \pi$.

I tried with the Fourier solution $$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \sin (\frac{n \pi x}{l}) \exp(\frac{-c^2n^2 \pi^2t}{l^2}),$$ where, $l=\pi,~c=1$, and $a_n=\frac{2}{l}\int_0^l \varphi(y)\sin (\frac{n \pi y}{l})dy$, to obtain $$f(x)=u(x,T)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \varphi(y)\sin (ny)dy\right) \sin (nx) e^{-n^2T},$$

$$=\int_0^\pi \frac{2}{\pi}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin (ny)  \sin (nx) e^{-n^2T} \right) \varphi(y) dy, $$
$$=\int_0^\pi k(x,y) \varphi(y) dy,$$ for a suitable kernal $k(x,y)$. I feel (3) and (4) can be rejected, but I have no justification. Can we fabricate option (1) in to (2) for a suitable $k$? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "fabricate (1) into (2)" mean? That multiple choice question asks which of (1),(2),(3),(4) is true. You have even found an answer.

Comment: How to eliminate others?  Can we rewrite option (1) in to (2) for a suitable kernal?

Comment: why ? (1) is the correct answer. the others are wrong.

Comment: Actually, this is a multiple select question, I need to know how can we eliminate the other options. In other words, is  there any contradiction while we assume $f(x)$ takes the forms in option 2,3,4? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @KurtG. Can we suggest some Dirichlet problems as counter examples ?

Comment: This is the first multiple choice exam that I see where the candidates are asked to give counter examples to the wrong answers. When they ask  "which of the following is true" and we know that (1) is true we are IMO done.

Comment: @KurtG. It is a multiple select question not a multiple choice. If we have some of the Dirichlet problems so that the initial function $\phi$ doesnot satisfy rest of the oprions (2,3,4), then I can make sure option 1 is the only true.

Comment: Whatever they call it. "which of the following is true" ? Does that help ?

Comment: @KurtG. Sorry..., I got your point, and, I have corrected it as  '.....which of the following is/are true......',

Comment: From (1) take the kernel $k(x,y)$ that solves $\int_0^\pi k(x,y)\varphi(y)\,dy=f(x)\,.$ Obviously, the other kernel $k'(x,y)=k(x,y)
-\delta_x(y)$ solves $\varphi(x)+\int_0^\pi k'(x,y)\varphi(y)\,dy=f(x)\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. That's fine...Thanks.... I hope $\delta_x(y)$ is Kronecker's, right? what about other options?

Comment: Dirac's $\delta$ not Kronecker's .  Other options ? Why ?

Comment: You can google that.